# sqlite3, python, CREATE TABLE - near "/": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to simply create a table in a database using python and sqlite. However, I need my db name to be given by the user. I managed to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as sqlite
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))


def create_table(dbname):
        sql = '''\
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ''' + dbname + ''' (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                        FIRSTNAME TEXT,
                        LASTNAME TEXT,
                        ACADEMIC_DEGREE TEXT,
                        DISCIPLINE TEXT
                '''

        connection = sqlite.connect(dbname, check_same_thread=False)
        try:
            with connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                try:
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                except sqlite.DatabaseError, dbe:
                    print dbe
        finally:
            connection.close()

tmp = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
path = os.path.join(tmp[0], 'researchers.sql')
create_table(path)
```

However, my code does not create a table, but only gives me an error message: `near "/": syntax error`. What's wrong with this code? Where's the syntax error python mentions about, how to solve this?

**This code worked:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as sqlite
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))


def create_table(dbname):
        sql = '''
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ''' + str(dbname.split('.')[0]) + ''' (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                        FIRSTNAME TEXT,
                        LASTNAME TEXT,
                        ACADEMIC_DEGREE TEXT,
                        DISCIPLINE TEXT
                    )
                '''

        connection = sqlite.connect(dbname, check_same_thread=False)
        try:
            with connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                try:
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                except sqlite.DatabaseError, dbe:
                    print dbe
        finally:
            connection.close()

create_table('researchers.sql')
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your closing your `CREATE TABLE` statement, the error comes from your first char inside the `'''`, which im also not sure is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your sql variable with this;

```
 sql = '''
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ''' + dbname + ''' (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                        FIRSTNAME TEXT,
                        LASTNAME TEXT,
                        ACADEMIC_DEGREE TEXT,
                        DISCIPLINE TEXT
                    )
                '''
```

Answer (score 1):

The table name can't have arbitrary characters in it, certainly not a `/`, so you can't `create_table(path)`. Choose a simple table name, such as "researchers".